# How does webservice application know soap call for a particular method,without using operation name in soap message? 

Tags: java, .net, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

Document/literal **WSDL** for myMethod

```
<types>
    <schema>
        <element name="xElement" type="xsd:int"/>
        <element name="yElement" type="xsd:float"/>
    </schema>
</types>

<message name="myMethodRequest">
    <part name="x" element="xElement"/>
    <part name="y" element="yElement"/>
</message>
<message name="empty"/>

<portType name="PT">
    <operation name="myMethod">
        <input message="myMethodRequest"/>
        <output message="empty"/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding .../>
```

Document/literal **SOAP message** for myMethod

```
<soap:envelope>
    <soap:body>
        <xElement>5</xElement>
        <yElement>5.0</yElement>
    </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

How does web service engine know above soap message for a particular method ?

How server application know which method soap message is calling on?

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/ link for reference

Comment: generic like webservice engine in websphere application server or .net etc

Comment: Different engines might do it in different ways.

Comment: please can you let me know how server application know which method soap message is calling on?

Comment: FYI, I don't believe that's a valid document/literal service. It can have only one message part for input, and one for output. Also, it must use `type=`, not `element=` on the message parts.

Comment: @john Here is the link for ibm site for where I copied                  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/

Comment: Did you notice the article was published 31 Oct 2003?

Comment: ofcourse,but the soap message is still valid

Comment: My point is that the article may no longer be as useful 9 years later.

Answer (score 1):

Server will identify method based on parameter types and annotated with @Webmethod.
In case of two similar method, server will call last method specified in wsdl.